# Error When Trying To Run Python Script From HTML (Ajax)

Tags: python, html, button, server-side

I am an absolute beginner in HTML and I really have no idea what I am doing.  I have a website hosted by github and I would like it to execute a python script on my computer when the button on the website is pressed. Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
   <h1>Press The Button To Run The Python Script</h1>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id='script' name="scriptbutton" value=" Run Script " onclick="goPython()">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        function goPython(){
            $.ajax({
              url: "MYSCRIPT.py",
             context: document.body
            }).done(function() {
             alert('finished python script');;
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Mihkel/Desktop/MYSCRIPT.py' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

MYSCRIPT.py and the test.html file are located in the same directory. Do I have to modify the python script to make it run properly? The error to me seems like a permissions error is that true?

Comment: Do you mean: "When an internet visitor presses a button on your website, you would like a python script on your local personal computer to run" ?

Comment: @gibberish yes, that's what their question says.

Comment: How is your page being hosted?  Did you write a web server?  If you're not hosting the page in some way where you have execute permissions, you cannot do what you're asking.

Comment: This might help:  https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-web-application-using-flask-and-deploy-it-to-the-cloud-3551c985e492

Comment: My page is being hosted using githubs desktop app.